# Android how to remove hyperlink text format?

Tags: android, html, textview

i use my textview each word clickable use this code

```
private ClickableSpan getClickableSpan() {
    return new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) widget;
            String s = tv
                    .getText()
                    .subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),
                            tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();

            Log.d("tapped on:", s);
        }

        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
        }
    };
}

public static Integer[] getIndices(String s, char c) {
    int pos = s.indexOf(c, 0);
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (pos != -1) {
        indices.add(pos);
        pos = s.indexOf(c, pos + 1);
    }

    pos = s.indexOf("\n", 0);
    while (pos != -1) {
        indices.add(pos);
        pos = s.indexOf("\n", pos + 1);
    }

    Collections.sort(indices);

    return (Integer[]) indices.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

the problem is I set font color using HTML.fromHtml();

but when i use this hyperlink code that color is change blue

i want to remove hyperlink text format

blue font color, underline, blue box when click hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem use this code

```
public class NonUnderlinedClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan 
{
    @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {            
           ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

i use ClickableSpan so NoURLUnderline is doesn't work :)

Comment: what if you want to maintain the underlind but remove the blue color?